# How to group rows in a dataframe by quarters?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 213 rows and 2 columns (*Date* and *Article*). The final aim is to reduce the number of rows by grouping the **Date** by quarterly. Obviously, I want texts from the **Article** column to be merged accordingly.

Let's take an example.

```
Date <- c("2000-01-05", "2000-02-03", "2000-03-02", "2000-03-30", "2000-04-13", "2000-05-11", "2000-06-08", "2000-07-06", "2000-09-14", "2000-10-05", "2000-10-19", "2000-11-02", "2000-12-14")
Article <- c("Long Text","Long Text","Long Text","Long Text","Long Text","Long Text","Long Text","Long Text","Long Text","Long Text","Long Text","Long Text","Long Text")

Date <- data.frame(Date)
Article <- data.frame(Article)

df <- cbind(Date, Article)

#Dataframe

Date           Article
1  2000-01-05 Long Text
2  2000-02-03 Long Text
3  2000-03-02 Long Text
4  2000-03-30 Long Text
5  2000-04-13 Long Text
6  2000-05-11 Long Text
7  2000-06-08 Long Text
8  2000-07-06 Long Text
9  2000-09-14 Long Text
10 2000-10-05 Long Text
11 2000-10-19 Long Text
12 2000-11-02 Long Text
13 2000-12-14 Long Text
```

The final output I would like to obtain is the following:

```
Date         Article
1  2000 Q1   Long Text, Long Text, Long Text, Long Text
2  2000 Q2   Long Text, Long Text, Long Text
3  2000 Q3   Long Text, Long Text
4  2000 Q4   Long Text, Long Text, Long Text, Long Text
```

Essentially, the rows have been grouped together by quarters as well as the corresponding text.

I tried to look around but I have no idea how to do it, unofrtunately.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `as.yearqtr` from `zoo` to do summarization

```
library(zoo)
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Article = toString(Article)),.(Date = as.yearqtr(as.IDate(Date)))]
#   Date                                    Article
#1: 2000 Q1 Long Text, Long Text, Long Text, Long Text
#2: 2000 Q2            Long Text, Long Text, Long Text
#3: 2000 Q3                       Long Text, Long Text
#4: 2000 Q4 Long Text, Long Text, Long Text, Long Text
```

Comment: thanks! It works in the example but in my real dataframe I get the following error: `Error in as.Date.default(x, tz = tz, ...) : 
  do not know how to convert 'x' to class “Date”`.Any idea?

Comment: @Arma_91 If the `Date` format is in `"%Y-%m-%d`"` format, you don't have to specify the `format` argument in `as.Date` or `as.IDate` (here it is the default Date format), but if it is different, then specify the `format` or use `library(anytime); `as.yearqtr(anydate(Date))` if the format needs to be automatically picked up and do the conversion (assuming that the format is available in `getFormats()`

Comment: my format is indeed `%Y-%d-%m`. So it should be something like this: `setDT(df)[, .(Article = toString(Article)),.(Date = as.yearqtr(as.IDate(Date)), format = "%Y-%d-%m)]`? I don't manage to make it work. Just get the same error.

Comment: @Arma_91 The `format` should be inside the `as.IDate` i.e. `as.IDate(Date, format = "%Y-%d-%m")`

Comment: Got it! I had to change the name of a column. Thanks a lot! Life saver!

Answer (score 3):

One `dplyr` and `lubridate` option could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(Date = as.character(lubridate::quarter(ymd(Date), with_year = TRUE))) %>%
 summarise(Article = paste0(Article, collapse = ",")) 

  Date   Article                                
  <chr>  <chr>                                  
1 2000.1 Long Text,Long Text,Long Text,Long Text
2 2000.2 Long Text,Long Text,Long Text          
3 2000.3 Long Text,Long Text                    
4 2000.4 Long Text,Long Text,Long Text,Long Text
```

Comment: thanks! it works on the example but in the real date it says: "Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found." Any idea?

Comment: It is based on your sample data. If you use another date format, then you need to specify it. What is your actual date format?

Comment: thanks a lot! I sorted it out as you told me that! Big help thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
# Row-wise concatenate Article vec by the group of year & qtr: 

aggregate(list(Article = df$Article),

          by = list(Date = paste(gsub("[-].*", "", df$Date), quarters(df$Date), sep = " ")),

          paste, sep = ", ")
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(c("2000-01-05",
                                   "2000-02-03",
                                   "2000-03-02",
                                   "2000-03-30", "2000-04-13", "2000-05-11", "2000-06-08",
                                   "2000-07-06", "2000-09-14", "2000-10-05", "2000-10-19",
                                   "2000-11-02", "2000-12-14"),
                                 "%Y-%m-%d"),
            Article = c("Long Text","Long Text","Long Text","Long Text","Long Text","Long Text","Long Text","Long Text","Long Text","Long Text","Long Text","Long Text","Long Text"))
```